# No standing wave at high tension

Tags: forces, waves, string

Why transverse standing wave in a string is finished when there is a very high tension in string
.......I don't know the reason if tension increases speed then why there is no wave

Answer (score 1):

High tension, by itself, will not prevent formation of standing waves in a string. If the string will vibrate at all at its fundamental frequency, that vibration *is* a standing wave.

However: attenuation in a string is much stronger at higher frequencies, and higher tension raises the fundamental frequency.  Of course it also raises the frequencies of the harmonics, so all possible standing waves will be attenuated more quickly when the tension is increased.  If the attenuation is so strong at a given frequency that a wave at that frequency is mostly absorbed before it can travel the full length of the string and back (necessary for the self-interference that forms the standing wave), then the resultant standing wave can be so weak that it is difficult to detect.